# Editing admin pages in WordPress

Tags: plugins, admin

I’m trying to find information on how to edit admin pages in WordPress.

Custom pages can be overridden in the site template, but I still do not understand how to deal with the admin.

> Note: In my case this is the WooCommerce order edit page, but you may provide the generic solution to the problem. The main thing is to make changes to the admin page.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help you. But normally 3rd party premium plugins are considered to be off-topic for this Q+A. Have you already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786256/2199525? Seems a perfect match. This one https://hollerwp.com/customize-woocommerce-checkout-page/ seems promising as well.

Comment: @leymannx: Please note that the original intent of the OP is on topic, may be some wording is a bit off. I've now edited the question to fix that too.

Comment: @Fayaz – Please note that OP didn't tell us what they've tried themselves so far and where exactly they are stuck. Nor did they provide any context or background information. This question should be flagged and closed instead of being reworded. It still is too broad and therefore will lead to answers only of the same low quality. Bad.

Comment: @leymannx I respectfully disagree. The topic of `Editing admin pages` can be a couple of lines answer, the accepted answer reflects that. Having said that, it can be made into a very broad answer. Even so, it's borderline on topic. IMHO, to welcome new users, we should allow this much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no templates for the admin pages. You have two options to manipulate them, anyway:

1. Use filters to edit the pages (See the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request)).
2. Change the page using CSS ([also using a hook](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/apply-custom-css-to-admin-area/) or use an existing plugin like [Add Admin CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-admin-css/)).

There are more plugins that help you changing the admin backend - a recommendation depends a bit on what *exactly* you want to change.